# Get a block from an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array

```
   75.7740   70.6046   82.3458   43.8744   48.9764
   74.3132    3.1833   69.4829   38.1558   44.5586
   39.2227   27.6923   31.7099   76.5517   64.6313
   65.5478    4.6171   95.0222   79.5200   70.9365
   17.1187    9.7132    3.4446   18.6873   75.4687
```

and I would like to get the for example from (1,1) to (2,2) sub array

```
3.1833   69.4829  
27.6923   31.7099
```

When I'm making some calculation on the sub array I would like to take affect in the big array as well.

For example I have a Matrix class

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    unsigned rows, cols;
    T* data_;
        .....
}
```

Testing

```
MatrixXd u(5, 5);
MatrixXd d(2, 2);
....
u.subblock(1,1,2,2) = d*d
or
u(1,1,2,2) = d*d
```

I already overloaded the some operators like ()/*-+ etc, but I have no idea hove can I manipulate sub array.

Comment: How ` 38.1558   44.5586
      27.6923   31.7099` related to `(1,1) to (2,2) sub array`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how those 4 numbers are the sub-array from (1,1) to (2,2).  What notation is that?

Comment: Sorry I fixed that, (starting row, starting column, end row, end column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
u.subblock(1,1,2,2) = d*d
```

To get a line such as the above work, you can define a helper class:

```
template<class T>
class SubMatrix {
private:
    Matrix<T> *origin;
    unsigned int sr, sc, er, ec; // start and end row and column
        .....
};
```

Then your `Matrix::subblock` function returns a `SubMatrix` for which `operator =` is overloaded taking a `Matrix` (and one taking a `SubMatrix` and possibly other operators, and an `operator =` in `Matrix` taking a `SubMatrix` etc).

This helper class would then read to/write from the original matrix at a given window.

Comment: Your solution is working fine, now I got a different problem when I would like to return the orginal matrix
`template<class T>
Matrix<T> SubMatrix<T>::getMatrix(){
 return *origin;
}`
`Matrix<T> tmp = m.getMatrix();` and I'm getting the following  error: passing ‘const SubMatrix<double>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Matrix<T> SubMatrix<T>::getMatrix() [with T = double]’ discards qualifiers

Comment: It basically says that `m` is `const`. Your function `getMatrix()` should be defined as `... getMatrix() const;`. As you know, only the `type name(args) const;` functions of a class can be called on its `const` objects.

Answer (score 1):

One possible design for this is for the sub-matrix to become a *view* onto the relevant part of the main matrix. In other words, instead of managing its own storage, the view would simply reuse the main matrix's storage. When the view is modified, so will be the main matrix.

Numerical Python uses such a design with great deal of success.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to write it, that's one thing.

If you want a solution already written, check out Boost's [multi_array](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_array/).  You get that as well as N-dimensional matrices with some storage overhead optimization.

The specific classes you'd use are [boost::multi_array_ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_ref) and [boost::const_multi_array_ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#const_multi_array_ref)

*(Note: Fair warning from experience...these are not ready for storing C++11 move-only types like `unique_ptr` at this point in time.)*

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that your matrix class is supporting too many operations. Minimum required operations will look like this:

```
class MatrixI {
public:
  virtual int SizeX() const=0;
  virtual int SizeY() const=0;
  virtual float Map(int x, int y) const=0;
}
```

So to make it all work, you should implement your operations +,* etc based on the above interface:

```
class Matrix {
public:
   /* +,* -operations here */
private:
   MatrixI *ptr; // owned ptr
};
```

Then submatrix is operation from MatrixI to MatrixI:

```
class SubMatrix : public MatrixI {
public:
SubMatrix(MatrixI *orig, int pos_x, int pos_y, int sx, int sy);
/* implement minimum required functions here */
private:
  MatrixI *orig;
  int pos_x, pos_y;
  int sx,sy;
};
```